# How to enable normal scroll behavior, at certain DIV element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a bit of trouble getting a one-page scroll to behave the way I want it to. I would like the first  to be full page and when they scroll down, it will full page scroll to the next  element. But when they reach the 2nd section element - it will revert to regular scrolling behavior. This is because the rest of the page is not full page or one page.

I basically want the intro to be a full page, and then do a full page scroll into the next section where they can freely scroll down normally. When they scroll back up to the first section it should full page scroll again to the intro.

I'm using the below code. This is working for the full page transition into section 2, but I can't figure out how to revert to normal scrolling behavior after they reach section 2.

```
$('section').height($(window).height());
        /*set the class 'active' to the first element
         this will serve as our indicator*/
        $('section').first().addClass('active');

        /* handle the mousewheel event together with
         DOMMouseScroll to work on cross browser */
        $(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();//prevent the default mousewheel scrolling
            var active = $('section.active');
            //get the delta to determine the mousewheel scrol UP and DOWN
            var delta = e.originalEvent.detail < 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 ? 1 : -1;

            //if the delta value is negative, the user is scrolling down
            if (delta < 0) {
                //mousewheel down handler
                next = active.next();
                //check if the next section exist and animate the anchoring
                if (next.length) {
                    /*setTimeout is here to prevent the scrolling animation
                     to jump to the topmost or bottom when
                     the user scrolled very fast.*/
                    var timer = setTimeout(function () {
                        /* animate the scrollTop by passing
                        the elements offset top value */
                        $('body, html').animate({
                            scrollTop: next.offset().top
                        }, 'slow');

                        // move the indicator 'active' class
                        next.addClass('active')
                            .siblings().removeClass('active');

                        clearTimeout(timer);
                    }, 800);
                }

            } else {
                //mousewheel up handler
                /*similar logic to the mousewheel down handler
                except that we are animate the anchoring
                to the previous sibling element*/
                prev = active.prev();

                if (prev.length) {
                    var timer = setTimeout(function () {
                        $('body, html').animate({
                            scrollTop: prev.offset().top
                        }, 'slow');

                        prev.addClass('active')
                            .siblings().removeClass('active');

                        clearTimeout(timer);
                    }, 800);
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: can you JsFiddle it? it's hard in this way to understand your meaning of "full page scroll" and "regular scroll"

Comment: I want the header to be 100% of the viewport of the browser. Then scrolling down would transition from the header to the rest of the page. The rest of the page would not be full page and have content sprawling down that they could just scroll normally through.

Answer (score 0):

To hide scrollbars of the browser (and thus to have the look of full page) apply `overflow:hidden` css-property to body like

```
$(document.body).css('overflow', 'hidden');
```

When you scrolled down via javascript to a section where the user should be able to scroll with standard scrolls just let scrollbar-handling be done automatically again by

```
$(document.body).css('overflow', 'auto');
```

*So apply the first javascript-snippet whenever you scrolled via javascript to a fullpage view apply the latter everytime you scrolled to a normal scrollable section again.*

Comment: I'm very new to jquery and I got this code from another answer on stack that worked well. Could you tell me how to implement this answer in the context of the above snippet? The code I'm using now, just doesn't allow any scrolling passed the 2nd section because there is no other sections to scroll to.